# group multiplication using R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, dplyr

I want the group multiplication of each group dates.
format no 1 - the expected output should be as below:

```
 date      Bucket             D        DP    
1/31/2013   bkt 0             NA
1/31/2013   bkt 1(10-20)      NA
1/31/2013   bkt 2(20-30)      NA
1/31/2013   bkt 3(30-40)      NA
1/31/2013   bkt 4(40+)        NA
2/28/2013   bkt 0             NA
2/28/2013   bkt 1(10-20)      3.00
2/28/2013   bkt 2(20-30)      3.63
2/28/2013   bkt 3(30-40)      101
2/28/2013   bkt 4(40+)        102
3/30/2013   bkt 0             NA
3/30/2013   bkt 1(10-20)      0.55
3/30/2013   bkt 2(20-30)      0.40
3/30/2013   bkt 3(30-40)      103
3/30/2013   bkt 4(40+)        104
4/31/2013   bkt 0             NA
4/31/2013   bkt 1(10-20)      4.25              
4/31/2013   bkt 2(20-30)      3.65              
4/31/2013   bkt 3(30-40)      105        
4/31/2013   bkt 4(40+)        106        
5/30/2013   bkt 0             NA
5/30/2013   bkt 1(10-20)      2.34  13608   (108 * 105 *  0.40 *  3.00)         
5/30/2013   bkt 2(20-30)      4.10  4536    (108 * 105 * 0.40)                  
5/30/2013   bkt 3(30-40)      107   11340   (108 * 105)   
5/30/2013   bkt 4(40+)        108   108     (108)
```

format 2 
for more understanding - i have arranged the data in the below manner:

```
1/31/2013  2/28/2013  3/30/2013 4/31/2013  5/30/2013  DP   
NA         NA         NA        NA         NA         NA
NA         3.00       0.55      4.25       2.34       13608   (108 * 105 *  0.40 *  3.00)
NA         3.63       0.40      3.65       4.10       4536    (108 * 105 * 0.40)
NA         101        103       105        107        11340   (108 * 105)
NA         102        104       106        108        108     (108)
```

but my CSV file will be in the format no 1 manner:
please help, Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you organize your data in a way that the diagonal product makes more sense?

Comment: i'm not sure its a diagonal product, its a similar to it i guess.

Comment: @ChiPak please check the arrangements now. But my CSV will be in the format no 1 manner.

Answer (score 0):

I made up some data that's in the same format as yours:

```
set.seed(1)
DF <- data.frame( date = rep(c(ymd("2017-01-01", "2016-01-01", "2015-01-01", "2014-01-01", "2013-01-01")), each=5),
                  group = rep(1:5, each=5),
                  value = rnorm(25))
head(DF)

         date group       value
1  2017-01-01     1 -0.05612874
2  2017-01-01     1 -0.15579551
3  2017-01-01     1 -1.47075238
4  2017-01-01     1 -0.47815006
```

Here's how I did it:

```
M <- matrix(DF$value, ncol=5)
diag.M <- diag(M)
diag.product <- sapply(5:1, function(x) prod(diag.M[1:x]))
cbind(M, diag.product) %>%
      as.data.frame()
```

I convert `DF` to a `matrix`. I take the `diag` of the matrix (list of the diagonal values). I calculate the product of the `diag` from 5-to-1, 4-to-1, 3-to-1, etc using `sapply`. I column bind `cbind` the diag.product to the matrix and convert to `data.frame`.

Comment: Thanks Chi Pak, what is the number of buckets is increased, the moment there are 5 sets of bucket, but in the original dataset i have amlost 30 to 35 sets of Buckets.

Comment: As long as you have a symmetrical matrix, should be fine, I think.

Comment: there's a problem with my date function, the format of my date is - mm/dd/yyyy but in your code, its ymd, hence is showing an error -     Error in data.frame(date = rep(c(ymd("5/30/2013", "4/31/2013", "3/30/2013",  : 
  could not find function "ymd"

Comment: Install `install.packages("lubridate")`, then load `library(lubridate)`, then use `mdy` instead of `ymd`.

Comment: Are your `date`s not already in Date format? I only used `lubridate::ymd` because I had to make up data...

Comment: i'm not able to understand the above code: i need to use the csv file, load into R, but as per your code, i'm not sure where should i include the CSV and how to process it. Can you please explain it.

Comment: sapply(5:1, function(x) prod(diag.M[1:x]))
    [1] NA NA NA NA NA  ..... this is what is happening, all the NA's are priinting in result column.

Comment: tried with your code for 14*14 matrix, ran the below code: 

M <- matrix(csv.lossrate$N_RR_PCT, ncol = 14)
diag.M <- diag(M)
diag.product <- sapply(1:14, function(x) prod(diag.M[14:x]))
cbind(M, diag.product) %>%
  as.data.frame()

Error: 
as.data.frame()
Error in as.data.frame() : argument "x" is missing, with no default

Answer (score 0):

Consider a sliding conditional `prod` multiplication using `by` for each combination of *date* and *Bucket* factor levels. To verify, below prints out the factors in each multiplication but `print` line inside function is not needed:

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text='date      Bucket             D   
                 "1/31/2013"   "bkt 0"             NA
                 "1/31/2013"   "bkt 1(10-20)"      NA
                 "1/31/2013"   "bkt 2(20-30)"      NA
                 "1/31/2013"   "bkt 3(30-40)"      NA
                 "1/31/2013"   "bkt 4(40+)"        NA
                 "2/28/2013"   "bkt 0"             NA
                 "2/28/2013"   "bkt 1(10-20)"      3.00
                 "2/28/2013"   "bkt 2(20-30)"      3.63
                 "2/28/2013"   "bkt 3(30-40)"      101
                 "2/28/2013"   "bkt 4(40+)"        102
                 "3/30/2013"   "bkt 0"             NA
                 "3/30/2013"   "bkt 1(10-20)"      0.55
                 "3/30/2013"   "bkt 2(20-30)"      0.40
                 "3/30/2013"   "bkt 3(30-40)"      103
                 "3/30/2013"   "bkt 4(40+)"        104
                 "4/31/2013"   "bkt 0"             NA
                 "4/31/2013"   "bkt 1(10-20)"      4.25              
                 "4/31/2013"   "bkt 2(20-30)"      3.65              
                 "4/31/2013"   "bkt 3(30-40)"      105        
                 "4/31/2013"   "bkt 4(40+)"        106        
                 "5/30/2013"   "bkt 0"             NA
                 "5/30/2013"   "bkt 1(10-20)"      2.34
                 "5/30/2013"   "bkt 2(20-30)"      4.10
                 "5/30/2013"   "bkt 3(30-40)"      107
                 "5/30/2013"   "bkt 4(40+)"        108
                 "6/30/2013"   "bkt 0"             NA
                 "6/30/2013"   "bkt 1(10-20)"      4.00
                 "6/30/2013"   "bkt 2(20-30)"      5.00
                 "6/30/2013"   "bkt 3(30-40)"      109.00
                 "6/30/2013"   "bkt 4(40+)"        110.00
                 "7/30/2013"   "bkt 0"             NA
                 "7/30/2013"   "bkt 1(10-20)"      8.00
                 "7/30/2013"   "bkt 2(20-30)"      7.00
                 "7/30/2013"   "bkt 3(30-40)"      111.00
                 "7/30/2013"   "bkt 4(40+)"        112.00', header=TRUE)
```

**Code**

```
 # ADD LEVEL COLUMNS
df$datelvl <- as.integer(as.factor(df$date))
df$bucketlvl <- as.integer(as.factor(df$Bucket))

# RUN CONDITIONAL prod BY EACH LEVEL WITH by
df$DP <- as.numeric(by(df, df[,c("bucketlvl", "datelvl")], FUN=function(i) {

  if(i$datelvl[1] >= 5) {  # CONDITION FOR NUMBER OF BUCKET GROUP
      tmp <- as.numeric(df[(df$datelvl==i$datelvl[1] & df$bucketlvl==5) |
                           (df$datelvl==i$datelvl[1]-1 & df$bucketlvl==4) |
                           (df$datelvl==i$datelvl[1]-2 & df$bucketlvl==3) |
                           (df$datelvl==i$datelvl[1]-3 & df$bucketlvl==2) |
                           (df$datelvl==i$datelvl[1]-4 & df$bucketlvl==1) ,"D"])
  } else {
    tmp <- NA        
  } 

  print(tmp[i$bucketlvl[1]:length(tmp)])      
  prod(tmp[i$bucketlvl[1]:length(tmp)])

}))
```

Print Output

```
# [1] NA
# [1] NA NA
# [1] NA NA NA
# [1] NA NA NA NA
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA
# [1] NA
# [1] NA NA
# [1] NA NA NA
# [1] NA NA NA NA
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA
# [1] NA
# [1] NA NA
# [1] NA NA NA
# [1] NA NA NA NA
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA
# [1]     NA   3.63 103.00 106.00
# [1]   3.63 103.00 106.00
# [1] 103 106
# [1] 106
# [1]  NA 106
# [1]    NA   3.0   0.4 105.0 108.0
# [1]   3.0   0.4 105.0 108.0
# [1]   0.4 105.0 108.0
# [1] 105 108
# [1] 108
# [1]     NA   0.55   3.65 107.00 110.00
# [1]   0.55   3.65 107.00 110.00
# [1]   3.65 107.00 110.00
# [1] 107 110
# [1] 110
# [1]     NA   4.25   4.10 109.00 112.00
# [1]   4.25   4.10 109.00 112.00
# [1]   4.1 109.0 112.0
# [1] 109 112
# [1] 112
```

Dataframe Output

```
#         date       Bucket      D datelvl bucketlvl        DP
# 1  1/31/2013        bkt 0     NA       1         1        NA
# 2  1/31/2013 bkt 1(10-20)     NA       1         2        NA
# 3  1/31/2013 bkt 2(20-30)     NA       1         3        NA
# 4  1/31/2013 bkt 3(30-40)     NA       1         4        NA
# 5  1/31/2013   bkt 4(40+)     NA       1         5        NA
# 6  2/28/2013        bkt 0     NA       2         1        NA
# 7  2/28/2013 bkt 1(10-20)   3.00       2         2        NA
# 8  2/28/2013 bkt 2(20-30)   3.63       2         3        NA
# 9  2/28/2013 bkt 3(30-40) 101.00       2         4        NA
# 10 2/28/2013   bkt 4(40+) 102.00       2         5        NA
# 11 3/30/2013        bkt 0     NA       3         1        NA
# 12 3/30/2013 bkt 1(10-20)   0.55       3         2        NA
# 13 3/30/2013 bkt 2(20-30)   0.40       3         3        NA
# 14 3/30/2013 bkt 3(30-40) 103.00       3         4        NA
# 15 3/30/2013   bkt 4(40+) 104.00       3         5        NA
# 16 4/31/2013        bkt 0     NA       4         1        NA
# 17 4/31/2013 bkt 1(10-20)   4.25       4         2        NA
# 18 4/31/2013 bkt 2(20-30)   3.65       4         3        NA
# 19 4/31/2013 bkt 3(30-40) 105.00       4         4        NA
# 20 4/31/2013   bkt 4(40+) 106.00       4         5        NA
# 21 5/30/2013        bkt 0     NA       5         1        NA
# 22 5/30/2013 bkt 1(10-20)   2.34       5         2  13608.00
# 23 5/30/2013 bkt 2(20-30)   4.10       5         3   4536.00
# 24 5/30/2013 bkt 3(30-40) 107.00       5         4  11340.00
# 25 5/30/2013   bkt 4(40+) 108.00       5         5    108.00
# 26 6/30/2013        bkt 0     NA       6         1        NA
# 27 6/30/2013 bkt 1(10-20)   4.00       6         2  23628.28
# 28 6/30/2013 bkt 2(20-30)   5.00       6         3  42960.50
# 29 6/30/2013 bkt 3(30-40) 109.00       6         4  11770.00
# 30 6/30/2013   bkt 4(40+) 110.00       6         5    110.00
# 31 7/30/2013        bkt 0     NA       7         1        NA
# 32 7/30/2013 bkt 1(10-20)   8.00       7         2 212724.40
# 33 7/30/2013 bkt 2(20-30)   7.00       7         3  50052.80
# 34 7/30/2013 bkt 3(30-40) 111.00       7         4  12208.00
# 35 7/30/2013   bkt 4(40+) 112.00       7         5    112.00
```

Comment: What is my input has almost 100 buckets, then that will be a problem here right? is there any way i can take the input as CSV instead of read.table.

Comment: Absolutely you cause read from file: `read.table('filename.csv', sep=",")` or its wrapper, `read.csv('filename.csv')`. Here, *text* is used to show reproducible example for future readers. And go ahead and check against 100 buckets (assuming there 100 dates) as this matches levels.

Comment: Hi, I tried pulling the CSV file and i got the output. But the problem here is, the format in which you gave me the solution is the Format #2, But i want the solution in Format #1. Please check the first part of my question. Can you please help me with the First format no 1 Solution.

Comment: Simply merge back to original dataframe, *df*. See edited extension.

Comment: HI, Parfait, please check this question - "diagonal Multiplication in R" this will give exact subset of my data set and what exactly i'm expecting. thanks.

Comment: Hi Parfait, Can you please have a look at the below questions, one the user replied to it but didnt get the exact output. please check the below link: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44704224/diagonal-product-multiplication-using-r/44706209#44706209

Comment: Hi Parfait, Did you get chance to check the above link? please check i need some guidance on it.

Comment: See updated code. No helper df or reshape is used. It should work here and on other question.

Comment: its not working for the 14 groups, each group has 14 rows, means 14*14 matrix. How can you check my csv?

Comment: You need to adjust. This runs for 5 bucket groups. Did you extend the bracket subset `df[..]`? And no where do you show a desired result of a square matrix, only long formatted dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

An approach I came up with using base R (data is the same as @Parfait):

```
# Split the group
l1 <- tapply(df$D, df$date, identity)
# Get the corresponding elements in the group and remove the first one (NA)
es <- mapply(`[`, l1, seq_along(l1))[-1]
# Then get cummulative product and put them into df
DP <- c(rep(NA, nrow(df) - length(es)),
        Reduce(`*`, es, right=TRUE, accumulate=TRUE))

df$DP <- DP
df

#         date       Bucket      D    DP
# 1  1/31/2013        bkt 0     NA    NA
# 2  1/31/2013 bkt 1(10-20)     NA    NA
# 3  1/31/2013 bkt 2(20-30)     NA    NA
# 4  1/31/2013 bkt 3(30-40)     NA    NA
# 5  1/31/2013   bkt 4(40+)     NA    NA
# 6  2/28/2013        bkt 0     NA    NA
# 7  2/28/2013 bkt 1(10-20)   3.00    NA
# 8  2/28/2013 bkt 2(20-30)   3.63    NA
# 9  2/28/2013 bkt 3(30-40) 101.00    NA
# 10 2/28/2013   bkt 4(40+) 102.00    NA
# 11 3/30/2013        bkt 0     NA    NA
# 12 3/30/2013 bkt 1(10-20)   0.55    NA
# 13 3/30/2013 bkt 2(20-30)   0.40    NA
# 14 3/30/2013 bkt 3(30-40) 103.00    NA
# 15 3/30/2013   bkt 4(40+) 104.00    NA
# 16 4/31/2013        bkt 0     NA    NA
# 17 4/31/2013 bkt 1(10-20)   4.25    NA
# 18 4/31/2013 bkt 2(20-30)   3.65    NA
# 19 4/31/2013 bkt 3(30-40) 105.00    NA
# 20 4/31/2013   bkt 4(40+) 106.00    NA
# 21 5/30/2013        bkt 0     NA    NA
# 22 5/30/2013 bkt 1(10-20)   2.34 13608
# 23 5/30/2013 bkt 2(20-30)   4.10  4536
# 24 5/30/2013 bkt 3(30-40) 107.00 11340
# 25 5/30/2013   bkt 4(40+) 108.00   108
```

Comment: Great work, it worked for the same dataset as mentioned in the above question. But when i tried the same code for my huge data set, the last column DP shows NA for all the rows. In my  data-set there  are 16 groups of 14 buckets (bkt(0) to btk(13)) - so intotal 224 rows. Will there be any changes in the above code?

Comment: Are you able to provide the subset of your data? I assumed that the number of groups would be equal to the number of buckets.

Comment: no of Group are 16, and each group has: 14 # buckets, will it create a problem?

Comment: I guess it will be easier to think in term of the #2 format you show, so it will be a 14 by 16 matrix, right? How do you define the diagonal product?

Comment: you mean to say, this code will only work for when there's n*n matrix, as it is working for the question data set which has 5 rows and 5 columns, hence we are getting the correct answer, but in my actual dataset it has 14 rows and 16 column - so its not working.

Comment: Yes, I would guess so.

Comment: HI, Jasan, please check this question - "diagonal Multiplication in R" this will give exact subset of my data set and what exactly i'm expecting. thanks.

Comment: Hi Jason did you get time to check it.??