# Diagonal product multiplication

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, dplyr

I want the diagonal multiplication of each group dates.

main Data Set:

```
 date      Bucket                 D            
1/31/2013   bkt 0                  NA
1/31/2013   bkt 1(10-20)           NA
1/31/2013   bkt 2(20-30)           NA
1/31/2013   bkt 3(30-40)           NA
1/31/2013   bkt 4(40+)             NA
2/28/2013   bkt 0                  NA
2/28/2013   bkt 1(10-20)          3.00
2/28/2013   bkt 2(20-30)          3.63
2/28/2013   bkt 3(30-40)          101
2/28/2013   bkt 4(40+)            102
3/30/2013   bkt 0                  NA
3/30/2013   bkt 1(10-20)          0.55
3/30/2013   bkt 2(20-30)          0.40
3/30/2013   bkt 3(30-40)          103
3/30/2013   bkt 4(40+)            104
4/31/2013   bkt 0                 NA
4/31/2013   bkt 1(10-20)          4.25              
4/31/2013   bkt 2(20-30)          3.65              
4/31/2013   bkt 3(30-40)          105        
4/31/2013   bkt 4(40+)            106        
5/30/2013   bkt 0                  NA
5/30/2013   bkt 1(10-20)          2.34      
5/30/2013   bkt 2(20-30)          4.10      
5/30/2013   bkt 3(30-40)          107                       
5/30/2013   bkt 4(40+)            108       
6/31/2013   bkt 0                 NA     
6/31/2013   bkt 1(10-20)          4         
6/31/2013   bkt 2(20-30)          5                
6/31/2013   bkt 3(30-40)          109       
6/31/2013   bkt 4(40+)            110       
7/30/2013   bkt 0                 NA
7/30/2013   bkt 1(10-20)          8         
7/30/2013   bkt 2(20-30)          7            
7/30/2013   bkt 3(30-40)         111           
7/30/2013   bkt 4(40+)           112        

Diagonal multiplication is as follows: 

1/31/2013 to 5/30/2013
2/28/2013 to 6/31/2013
3/30/2013 to 7/30/2013

each time we incrementing the next group of dates for diagonal product. 

 as so on ... the dates ranges from 1/31/2013 to 12/31/2016.
```

Expected Output:

```
  date      Bucket                 D         DP
1/31/2013   bkt 0                  NA
1/31/2013   bkt 1(10-20)           NA
1/31/2013   bkt 2(20-30)           NA
1/31/2013   bkt 3(30-40)           NA
1/31/2013   bkt 4(40+)             NA
2/28/2013   bkt 0                  NA
2/28/2013   bkt 1(10-20)          3.00
2/28/2013   bkt 2(20-30)          3.63
2/28/2013   bkt 3(30-40)          101
2/28/2013   bkt 4(40+)            102
3/30/2013   bkt 0                  NA
3/30/2013   bkt 1(10-20)          0.55
3/30/2013   bkt 2(20-30)          0.40
3/30/2013   bkt 3(30-40)          103
3/30/2013   bkt 4(40+)            104
4/31/2013   bkt 0                 NA
4/31/2013   bkt 1(10-20)          4.25              
4/31/2013   bkt 2(20-30)          3.65              
4/31/2013   bkt 3(30-40)          105        
4/31/2013   bkt 4(40+)            106        
5/30/2013   bkt 0                  NA
5/30/2013   bkt 1(10-20)          2.34      13608   (108 * 105 *  0.40 *  3.00) 
5/30/2013   bkt 2(20-30)          4.10      4536    (4.10  108 * 105 *  0.40)       
5/30/2013   bkt 3(30-40)          107       11340   (108 * 105)                 
5/30/2013   bkt 4(40+)            108       108     (108)
6/31/2013   bkt 0                 NA     
6/31/2013   bkt 1(10-20)          4         23628.275  (110 * 107 * 3.65 * 0.55)   
6/31/2013   bkt 2(20-30)          5         42960.5    (110 * 107 * 3.65)         
6/31/2013   bkt 3(30-40)          109       1170       (110 * 109 )
6/31/2013   bkt 4(40+)            110       110        (100)
7/30/2013   bkt 0                 NA
7/30/2013   bkt 1(10-20)          8         216627.6   (112 * 109 * 4.10 * 4.25)
7/30/2013   bkt 2(20-30)          7         50971.2    (112 * 109 * 4.10)     
7/30/2013   bkt 3(30-40)         111        12432      (112 * 109)   
7/30/2013   bkt 4(40+)           112        112        (112)
```

In the output we need to display only these columns: Date, Bucket, D and DP, as DP is the result of the multiplication. 
Anything in () is only for explanation of the Result came. no need to show that in column.

User's code with Errors:

```
d <- read.csv("lossrate.csv", header=TRUE)
> d$date = as.Date(d$date, format="%m/%d/%Y")
> r <- reshape2::dcast(data=d, Bucket ~ date, value.var="D")[-1, -2]
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
> mat <- as.matrix(r[-1])
> myD <- col(mat) - row(mat)
> rg <- range(myD)
> out <- sapply(seq(rg[1], rg[2]), function(x) 
+   `length<-`(rev(cumprod(rev(mat[myD==x]))), nrow(mat)))[,1:ncol(mat)]
> out[, colSums(is.na(out)) > 0] <- NA
> colnames(out) <- colnames(mat) # add dates as headers
> out <- reshape2::melt(cbind(r[1], out))
Using Bucket as id variables
> out <- merge(d, out, by.x=c("date", "Bucket"), by.y=c("variable",             "Bucket"), all=TRUE)
> output: 

         date       Bucket      D value
1  2013-01-31        bkt 0     NA    NA
2  2013-01-31 bkt 1(10-20)     NA    NA
3  2013-01-31 bkt 2(20-30)     NA    NA
4  2013-01-31 bkt 3(30-40)     NA    NA
5  2013-01-31   bkt 4(40+)     NA    NA
6  2013-02-28        bkt 0     NA    NA
7  2013-02-28 bkt 1(10-20)   3.00    NA
8  2013-02-28 bkt 2(20-30)   3.63    NA
9  2013-02-28 bkt 3(30-40) 101.00    NA
10 2013-02-28   bkt 4(40+) 102.00    NA
11 2013-03-30        bkt 0     NA    NA
12 2013-03-30 bkt 1(10-20)   0.55    NA
13 2013-03-30 bkt 2(20-30)   0.40    NA
14 2013-03-30 bkt 3(30-40) 103.00    NA
15 2013-03-30   bkt 4(40+) 104.00    NA
16 2013-05-30        bkt 0     NA    NA
17 2013-05-30 bkt 1(10-20)   2.34    NA
18 2013-05-30 bkt 2(20-30)   4.10    NA
19 2013-05-30 bkt 3(30-40) 107.00    NA
20 2013-05-30   bkt 4(40+) 108.00    NA
21 2013-07-30        bkt 0     NA    NA
22 2013-07-30 bkt 1(10-20)   8.00     1
23 2013-07-30 bkt 2(20-30)   7.00     1
24 2013-07-30 bkt 3(30-40) 111.00     1
25 2013-07-30   bkt 4(40+) 112.00     1
26       <NA>        bkt 0     NA    NA
27       <NA>        bkt 0     NA    NA
28       <NA> bkt 1(10-20)   4.25     2
29       <NA> bkt 1(10-20)   4.00     2
30       <NA> bkt 2(20-30)   5.00     2
31       <NA> bkt 2(20-30)   3.65     2
32       <NA> bkt 3(30-40) 109.00     2
33       <NA> bkt 3(30-40) 105.00     2
34       <NA>   bkt 4(40+) 106.00     2
35       <NA>   bkt 4(40+) 110.00     2
```

i have only changed the name of the csv file as per my data set thats it.

Comment: April doesnt have 31 days ;P (neither does june)

Comment: its just the sample data set :P anyways good catch :D 
hope you'll be able to catch the logic behind it ;)

Comment: i tried it, its not working, could you please be specific. Can you please show me the code, that you have tried ?

Comment: You've asked this question before...what is the diagal product of a `7x5` matrix? As I commented before, your matrix should be symmetrical...`MxM`, not `MxN`

Comment: @ChiPak ; it doesnt need to be symmetric. Try `mat = matrix(1:15, nc=5) ; col(mat) - row(mat)` The second matrix indicates the diagonals

Comment: @user20650: he's using code from a previous post, which was designed with a symmetrical matrix in mind

Comment: no this is the different question. in the first question we have only 5groups and we were doing the multiplication of 5 rows and 5 columns. But now we are doing the same thing 5*5 but every time we are incrementing the group one after the other. please check there are 7 groups in here, but the multiplication will be done only for 5 groups, 5 rows. 
Diagonal multiplication we as follows: 

1/31/2013 to 5/30/2013
2/28/2013 to 6/31/2013
3/30/2013 to 7/30/2013

each time we incrementing the next group of dates for diagonal product.

Comment: @ChiPak Do you see any difference between last and this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Change to date format so can be ordered
d$date = as.Date(d$date, format="%m/%d/%Y")
# Form matrix so easier to find diagonals
# [-1, -2] removes rows & columns of all NA
r <- reshape2::dcast(data=d, Bucket ~ date, value.var="D")[-1, -2]
# convert to matrix to allow row and col functions & remove non-numeric grouping
mat <- as.matrix(r[-1]) 

# Multiply diagonals
myD <- col(mat) - row(mat)
rg <- range(myD)
out <- sapply(seq(rg[1], rg[2]), function(x) 
          `length<-`(rev(cumprod(rev(mat[myD==x]))), nrow(mat)))[,1:ncol(mat)]
# remove if not needed: ensures four values in product
# not sure if needed: done to match expected outcome
out[, colSums(is.na(out)) > 0] <- NA 

# reshape
colnames(out) <- colnames(mat) # add dates as headers
out <- reshape2::melt(cbind(r[1], out))

# merge with original data
out <- merge(d, out, by.x=c("date", "Bucket"), by.y=c("variable", "Bucket"), all=TRUE)
```

Which gives

```
out[21:35,]

         date       Bucket      D     value
21 2013-05-30        bkt 0     NA        NA
22 2013-05-30 bkt 1(10-20)   2.34  13608.00
23 2013-05-30 bkt 2(20-30)   4.10   4536.00
24 2013-05-30 bkt 3(30-40) 107.00  11340.00
25 2013-05-30   bkt 4(40+) 108.00    108.00
26 2013-06-30        bkt 0     NA        NA
27 2013-06-30 bkt 1(10-20)   4.00  23628.28
28 2013-06-30 bkt 2(20-30)   5.00  42960.50
29 2013-06-30 bkt 3(30-40) 109.00  11770.00
30 2013-06-30   bkt 4(40+) 110.00    110.00
31 2013-07-30        bkt 0     NA        NA
32 2013-07-30 bkt 1(10-20)   8.00 212724.40
33 2013-07-30 bkt 2(20-30)   7.00  50052.80
34 2013-07-30 bkt 3(30-40) 111.00  12208.00
35 2013-07-30   bkt 4(40+) 112.00    112.00
```

---

**Data** (*corrected April and June dates)

```
d <- 
    structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("1/31/2013", 
"2/28/2013", "3/30/2013", "4/30/2013", "5/30/2013", "6/30/2013", 
"7/30/2013"), class = "factor"), Bucket = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L), .Label = c("bkt 0", "bkt 1(10-20)", "bkt 2(20-30)", "bkt 3(30-40)", 
"bkt 4(40+)"), class = "factor"), D = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
3, 3.63, 101, 102, NA, 0.55, 0.4, 103, 104, NA, 4.25, 3.65, 105, 
106, NA, 2.34, 4.1, 107, 108, NA, 4, 5, 109, 110, NA, 8, 7, 111, 
112)), .Names = c("date", "Bucket", "D"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-35L))
```

Comment: I followed your code: But i think you have the changed the data set's structure, did you separate the bkt and the bucktet's range ?? Request you to please explain the code, its working with the variables that are mentioned in the main question.

Comment: I copied and pasted the data from your question into a `read.table(text="...")` , although I did have to delete the extra comments that showed calculations. If the data in my answer is different , can you add your data to your question in an easier format to work with please - you can do this by adding the results of `dput(yourdataframe)`

Comment: can you please explain me this line: r <- reshape2::dcast(data=d, D ~ date, value.var="DP")[-1, -2]    - - - - what is D, what DP, where did you gets this from my main question?

Comment: from my copy and paste i got D, being the categories 0 , 1 (10-20), ... and DP the values NA, .., 3, 3.63 .... You can see this in the data i appended to the bottom of my answer. From your comments it appears this is not correct so can you edit your question with the results of dput please.

Comment: the only variable we need to use is: date, Bucket and D. DP is the output or  Result column DP is just for understanding the how show the results, WE dont need DP to be in the Dataset, DP will have the actual result after the code is executed. And we dont want to split the bucket.

Comment: I have edited the question, hope now its clear and easy to understand. Please let me know if any confusion. thanks.

Comment: @pradnya l thanks for the update but could you please add the results of `dput(df)` to your question - makes it much easier for me to move the data from your question in to my r session. I'll then update my answer, although it shouldnt make much difference. Ill add a bit more explanation.

Comment: is this what you want?

Comment: @pradnya ; perfect thanks : updated  - only needed to change D to Bucket. Ill add comments later / tomorrow.

Comment: are you splitting the buckets?? we shud not split the bucket!

Comment: thanks User, I will try it and let you know. Hope to see your comments. Thanks for all your help. Have a good day.

Comment: Hi User, It didnt worked, its shuffling the buckets. and the answer is not correct. Can you please try it at your end. thanks.

Comment: works as expected for me. The results from my code matches the expected outcome in your question (except for the entries for 7/30/2013 where your question has incorrect multiplication results). Bins are not reordered.

Comment: @pradnya ; can you add the code and error to your question please rather than the answer. Do you get an error when you copy and paste the code from my answer in to a fresh r session?

Comment: I have editted the question with the code that i used that you gave me, i directly copied it to my R session, only changed the name of the csv file.

Comment: @pradnya ; the `dcast` does not work properly given the message *Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length* . This can happen if there are duplicate rows between date and bucket - and notice there are a lot of NA dates. I suspect that when you run as.Date(d$date, format="%m/%d/%Y") that some values are not real dates . Remember I had to convert values from 31/4 and 31/6 to the 30th as otherwise they will not e converted - as they are not valid dates. If you want to use invalid dates, I suppose you could set the date to a factor and manually order it.

Comment: it worked, but only got this warning. - - - out <- reshape2::melt(cbind(r[1], out))
Using Bucket as id variables

Comment: @pradnya ; that's nothing to worry about: its a message not a warning. You can avoid it by setting the id.vars argument explicitely,  but melt takes a good guess at it in this case.

Comment: will this code work for 14*14 matrix, that is 14groups, each group has 14 buckets. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Difficult to say, but if your data is similarly organised, and you are using similar methods to multiply values over the range of dates , I dont see why not - perhaps some minor things will need tweaked. Try it and see ;)